# Create copy/paste button

Tags: ms-access-2007

Is it possible to create a 'COPY' and a 'PASTE' button in MS Access 2007 on a form.
Is there a code sample I could use, or a macro to copy a field and paste a field.

Comment: Great question for SuperUser?

Answer (score 1):

For API code to copy text to the clipboard:

http://www.mvps.org/access/api/api0049.htm

For getting data out of the currently active control, use:

```
  Screen.ActiveControl.Value
```

Put these two together and you should be able to figure it out.

If you can't, just post back and I'll provide more detailed instructions.

(there's also DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdCopy, but the data you're copying has to be selected for that to work, so it's actually harder to code that than it is to use the API for the clipboard)